# Firebase Firestore cloud function to watch user email updated

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

As part of building out a production app, I have a way to change a user's email address. I do this using

```
firebase.auth().updateEmail(newEmail);
```

This works well, and I am sent a email that says that my email has been changed. My issue is, I also get sent a link that allows me to recover my old email (a handy feature for security etc), but that causes the issue where the email address I store can get out of sync.

I store information about the user in a collection, when they change their email address using the above code, I also update the collection with their new email.

The problem is, if they click the recover link, there email address is reset back on on the user authentication side of things, but is not reset on my collection.

What I have been trying to find is something that behaves like this, but I cant find it

```
functions.auth.user().onEmailChange(async (newEmail, context) =>
{
    admin.firestore().collection(Collections.USERS_PRIVATE).doc(context.params.uid).update({ email: newEmail });
});
```

That way I can mirror my collection to always be in sync with the user authentication email address.

Answer (score 3):

I handle this problem with **custom email action handlers** and **Cloud Functions**. I only call the Cloud Function to update the email in Firestore as soon as the user has verified his new authentication email address. Therefore, you will only have valid and verified email addresses in Firestore. This means that if a user changes his email address with `firebase.auth().updateEmail(newEmail);`, but decides to revert back to his old authentication email through the `recoverEmail` action, you don´t have to do anything.

1. Define custom action url

Define your custom action url for automatically sent emails by Firebase in the Firebase Console e.g. `https://example.com/__/auth/action`. Firebase will append all necessary properties to your url such as the `oobCode` to verify a valid action and the `mode` which varies between:

- `resetPassword`,
- `recoverEmail` or
- `verifyEmail`

2. Write the action handler (ref. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler?hl=en)

```js
function handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode, continueUrl, lang) {
  // Try to apply the email verification code.
  auth.applyActionCode(actionCode).then(function(resp) {
    // Email address has been verified.

    // TODO: Display a confirmation message to the user.

    // TODO: Call your Cloud Function to update the email property in Firestore

  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Code is invalid or expired. Ask the user to verify their email address
    // again.
  });
}
```

3. Create the Cloud Function

Create a Cloud Function with the trigger `https.onCall` or `https.onRequest`, call it after a successful email verification and update the email field in Firestore.

Edit #1:
While this solution would work, I still couldn´t find a way to secure the Cloud Function during the `verifyEmail` process since there is a chance that the user isn´t logged in and I don´t know how to retrieve the `uid` during this step. I tried the same process with the `recoverEmail` handler, but ended up having the same issue. I created a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65599438/firebase-checkactioncode-for-recoveremail-with-cloud-functions) for this security issue, so maybe you will also benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

The only two triggers that exist from Firebase Authentication to Cloud Functions are when a user's account gets first created, and when a user account gets deleted. There is no trigger when the user account gets updated, or anything else.

It's a valid [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), but for the moment you'll have to do one of these:

1. Check for mismatching email address in your client-side code.
2. Handle the entire update of the email address in Cloud Functions.
3. Periodically check (recently updated) accounts for email addresses that are out of sync in Cloud Functions.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this by using a Custom Email Handler (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler). Just as you do it on the initial change, this lets you run some extra code when the user reverts the email back.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you include in your answer an example how this Custom Email Handler is to be used in context of this question?