# Firebase - checkActionCode for recoverEmail with Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

To keep the **Firebase Authentication** email addresses of users in sync with the `email` fields stored in **Firestore**, I also simultaneously update the `email` field in the user document when a user calls `firebase.auth().updateEmail(newEmail);`

However, calling `firebase.auth().updateEmail(newEmail);` triggers an automatic email to recover the old **Authentication** email address. Therefore, when the user recovers the old email address through the provided link, I also need to handle the synchronization with **Firestore**.

My current concept would be to add my own domain e.g. `https://example.com/__/auth/action` in **Customise action URL** in the **Firebase Console** and call a Cloud Function in case of a `recoverEmail` event.

```js
  public handleRecoverEmail(): void {
    let restoredEmail: string;

    this.auth.checkActionCode(this.oobCode).then(info => {
      restoredEmail = info.data.email;

      // TODO: Call Cloud Function and update email field in Firestore

      return this.auth.applyActionCode(this.oobCode);
    }).then(() => {
      window.location.href = 'startpage';
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

While this solution would work fine, I don´t know how to secure the Cloud Function without forcing the user to login during this step. Therefore, I tried to validate the `oobCode` in the Cloud Function with `checkActionCode(this.oobCode)` before applying it similarly to the frontend version. However, it seems like that there is no such method on the backend SDK.