# Unable to send email with user changes

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i'm trying to find an efficient way to get an email with user changes to their profile using Firebase Cloud functions and Javascript. A user profile has over 20 fields and i need an easy way of seeing user changes alone, not the entire profile.

I used to email the before and after of the profile but that's alot of code and its not easy to tell what changed.

My code:

```
exports.profileUpdateEmail = functions.firestore
  .document(`profiles/{profile}`)
  .onUpdate(async (changes) => {
    const oldProfile = changes.before.data();
    const newProfile = changes.after.data();

    const profileInfo = [
      "userName",
      "name",
      "email"...
    ];

      profileInfo.map(async (info) => {
        if (oldProfile.info !== newProfile.info) {
          try {
            const mailOptions = {
              from: ` "Admin" ${process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL}`,
              to: `${process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL}`,
              subject: `Professional Profile Update of ${oldProfile.userName}`,
              html: `<h1>Profile Changes</h1>
                                     <p>
                                        <b>UserID: </b>${oldProfile.user}<br>
                                     </p>
                                     <p>
                                       <b>${info}</b>
                                       <b>Before: ${oldProfile.info}
                                       <b>After: ${newProfile.info}
                                     </p>`,
            };
            await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
            console.log("Profile Update Email Sent!");
            return null;
          } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error from sending mail: ", error);
            return null;
          }
        }
      })
  });
```

When i run this code, no email comes through and GCP logging says `severity: DEBUG`.

2. This function will send an email for every field that's changed by a user so if a user makes 5 changes, that's 5 emails. How do i add on to the same email so that 5 changes made at once to a profile results in just one email?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Frank van Puffelen in this [`Stackoverflow Link`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74780008/18265702) it is not possible to get the mail for each update in the user profile.

> This isn't possible in Cloud Functions, as there's no trigger when the user object changes.
>
> Having a trigger when the user profile changes would be a useful addition to Cloud Functions, so I recommend you file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for it.
>
> The only workaround is to detect the emailVerified status client-side, call a [callable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) or [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) with the ID token, [verify that ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and then store the emailVerified value to Firestore from there.

Also have a look at this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59596442/18265702) for reference.

Comment: We must be speaking past other somehow because this is possible. There is an onUpdate trigger for when user changes a field in document(as long as you specify the collection) then something happens. I have received emails with user changes. Please see Firestore Triggers - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd

Comment: @Sandeep: My linked answer is about Auth triggers, while OP here uses Firestore triggers. The payload of an auth trigger is determined by the auth SDK, but here the payload is determined by the developer themselves - so it will include whatever data they store in the document.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick.

```
exports.profileUpdateEmail = functions.firestore
  .document(`profiles/{profile}`)
  .onUpdate(async (changes) => {
    try {
      const oldProfile = changes.before.data();
      const newProfile = changes.after.data();

      const profileInfo = ["userName", "name", "email"];

      // Check if we need to send an email
      let emailToBeSent = false;
      profileInfo.forEach((elem) => {
        if (oldProfile[elem] !== newProfile[elem]) emailToBeSent = true;
      });

      if (emailToBeSent) {
        const mailOptions = {
          from: ` "Admin" ${process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL}`,
          to: `${process.env.REACT_OUTGOING_EMAIL}`,
          subject: `Professional Profile Update of ${oldProfile.userName}`,
          html: `<h1>Profile Changes</h1>
                                   <p>
                                      <b>UserID: </b>${oldProfile.user}<br>
                                   </p>
                                   <p>
                                     <b>${info}</b>
                                     <b>Before: ${oldProfile.info}
                                     <b>After: ${newProfile.info}
                                   </p>`,
        };
        await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        console.log("Profile Update Email Sent!");
      }
      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error from sending mail: ", error);
      return null;
    }
  });
```

Note that you could use the [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) library to compare the elements of the two `oldProfile` and `newProfile` Objects, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463834/3371862.

Comment: Hey Coolkid, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed solution?